# Entity Framework CodeFirst vs DB First Migration Difference

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-database-first

My question is I have 2 projects. First project (Project 1) code-first and manipulate a database called FountainDB. The second project (Project 2) is the database first project which takes the model from FountainDB.

Here is, if I add a column on the code-first project another project unaware of this change.

I won't update my model (in project 2).

Do project 2 resumes to run? Or need to update the model from the database?

Thanks for now.

Comment: Are both of these projects in the same solution?

Comment: Not important. But not in same solution

Comment: If they are both a part of the same solution is there a reason you have chosen this design-that one project should use DB first and the other code first?

Comment: Oh sorry i wrote wrong. NOT in same solution

Comment: Have you thought of the idea of sharing an assembly between the two solutions so you don't duplicate work?